# XSLT match a element that has a specific parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I am quite new to XSLT, and I am trying to learn Xpath.

Let's suppose I have `match="warning/para"` and the XML file I want to analyze is:

```
<para>A normal paragraph.</para>
 <warning>
    <para>Warning paragraph one.</para>
    <para>Warning paragraph two.</para>
  </warning>
<para>Another normal paragraph.</para>
```

The matched `<para>` elements are just the one inside the `<warning>` element, or the `<para>` outside the warning element are matched as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single '/' means a direct descendant, so the engine expects a 'para' element inside a 'warning' element. Therefore only the nested para elements are matched.